# Is there a difference between Low-e Glass And Argon Gas?

Tags: windows

Is there a difference between Low-e Glass And Argon Gas?

My boss is trying to convince me that they are one in the same, despite my repeated attempts to differentiate the two for him. At this point, I need help to prove it to him that there is an extreme difference.

Answer (score 6):

[Low-E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_emissivity) windows are designed with material inside the glass or layered on it at the time of manufacture.

Argon Gas windows are multiple-pane windows that are air-tight with the gap between the panes filled with argon at assembly.

It is possible to get windows that are both at once. A Google search for Argon Windows brings up several links explaining Low-E windows and how [Argon and Low-E are not the same](http://construction.about.com/od/Doors-And-Windows/a/Argon-Gas-Window-Benefits-Of-Argon-Filled-Windows.htm).

Answer (score -1):

Low-E ideally works to reflect the ultraviolet rays, reject infrared and keep your home cooler in a warmer climate. Argon gas is an injected gas between the Panes of glass to help prevent cool air from penetrating in the winter. Argon gas is typically warranted in a colder climate. A simple rule of thumb is Low-E is and should be standard in a southern, warm climate, and argon gas should be standard in a colder climate. With all of that being said, it's become truly unfortunate and a market only for the extremely savvy. For those of you that are under the impression that you can purchase windows and feel confident in your decision without a hitch, you're likely in for a rude awakening. Many,many scam are perpetrated daily. Many examples, but I'll try to stick to the topic. (Low-E), many companies claim that theirs is better than another companies. How so?  Well, they claim their application and product performance is better. What I've found repeatedly without fail is that they'll sell the consumer on something that sounds great, Low-E squared, or Low-E cubed, and it's passed off as better, because it rejects more heat. But in reality it's the equivalent of a rushed painting project. No one would ever paint an interior wall by applying  3 or 4 coats at once. You sand, prime, then apply your base coat until you're satisfied with how it's turned out. That's exactly the gimmick behind low-e squared and cubed that companies like Milgard use.  On to Argon Gas, is it necessary even in a cold climate? Sure, but only if you're truly getting a iron clad warranty on the stabilization and life of the argon gas. How it's injected, stabilized and where it's manufactured are all key. In Denver, CO, or Minnesota, which is where Andersen Windows manufacturers and ships, let's say that you live in Phoenix, AZ, like I do. You will see in the fine print, if you look; that they guarantee the presence of 99.9% of argon gas upon manufacturing. That 99.9% goes all the way down to a worthless 5%-0.1% upon installation. So, what are you really paying for?

In summation, it's become extremely  difficult to pick the right product from the wrong and to identify the good companies from the bad. So much so that you truly need help with this process. It's not dissimilar to buying a used car. Consult a knowledgeable friend, confidant or professional before purchasing any type of home improvement project.

Comment: I removed the comments here since they were addressed to Jeff Ferland thus don't apply on this one. If you merge your accounts, you'll be able to leave comments on his answer. I've also removed your contact details and invitation to provide more information off-site; the point of this site is for sharing information so please do it here. Finally, you've made a lot of claims in this answer, but don't have any references to back it up; please update your post to include some. Thanks!

Comment: I don't need any references. Check mine, I'm a reference by career and title.

Comment: I left my contact information not out of an extreme desire to get more phone calls than I already do, but I'd always prefer to save someone from a huge mistake if possible. Scams are rampant here. It feels like the majority of my work is correcting other contractors work, sometimes pro Bono or at cost. I couldn't careless if it's left on there or not. Regular people policing this site is really strange to someone new to it who was simply trying to help. I thought I was answering a question.

Comment: If this site and your goal is to help people it may be difficult to do so in a limited, half-hearted capacity if one can simply only answer a question on this site, at most. It should be about helping people, not profiting from the lack of knowledge other people may have. Warped perspective.

Comment: Lastly, if the goal is to drive people and keep people on this site, why would you want me to post a link saying "See, I'm right", Wikipedia and Google also concur. That would be driving them somewhere else and you don't want that, right?

Comment: I designed the sales program for Renewal By Andersen in Phoenix. Would you like me to copy/paste their warranty on here? They're claims that can easily be substantiated by anyone that does a very small amount of homework. If I'm an expert and/or contributor, as many teachers are on other sites dedicated to helping students, they certainly aren't asked to substantiate their answers and show their work. I'm an expert in my field. I wouldn't dare delve into an area I didn't feel supremely confident in, like kitchen and bathroom remodeling or something of that nature.